# Combinations and variables

Tags: probability

$\text{Set} \ 1: [75,72,71,55,55,42,41,40,36]$

$\text{Set} \ 2: [89,63,62,58,50,44,44,43]$

$\text{Set} \ 3:  [50,49,49,46,36,35,35,35]$

$\text{Set} \ 4: [87,63,61,50,45,44,38,35]$

$\text{Set} \ 5: [92,54,44,43,42,35]$

I want to find all the combinations with these variables.

1. I need to use two number each from set $1$ - $4$ and one number from set $5$.
2. When I use the nine numbers it must be equal to between $570-600$.
   How would I do this? I have tried sitting down and just writing combinations but it's take a long time. Is there an easier way

Comment: are you allowed to pick the same element twice? Also the sets don't seam to have much order. This might be a problem designed for a computer.

Comment: I would use Excel myself.  Or like Jorge said, some computing power.

Comment: I m not allowed to use it twice unless it's written twice. I m trying to use Python to do the problem but I m having difficult setting it up. I have this question posted on another forum to and I thought I ask on a math site as well. Thanks

Comment: This same question was asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27803604/combinations-with-variables) today on [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: Yes I posted both places in hopes of getting some good suggestions

Answer (score 1):

There are ${9 \choose 2}{8 \choose 2}^36=36\cdot 28^3 \cdot 6 = 4741632$ choices.  A program with lots of loops can do that quickly.